# How to call StoredProcedure from CrystalReport?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I'd like to call a Stored Procedure from a crystal report and assign retrieved value to 
a field in report?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call Stored Procedure from crystal report,

Set data source of report to Stored Procedure (DataBase Expert Wizard).
That procedure must met thses requirement

1- You must create a package that defines the REF CURSOR (type of field that will be retrieved).

2- The procedure must have a parameter that is a REF CURSOR type. This is
because CR uses this parameter to access and define the result set that the
stored procedure returns.

3- The REF CURSOR parameter must be defined as IN OUT (read/write
mode).

4- Parameters can only be input (IN) parameters. CR is not designed to work
with OUT parameters.

5- The REF CURSOR variable must be opened and assigned its query within
the procedure.

6- The stored procedure can only return one record set. The structure of this
record set must not change, based on parameters.

7- The stored procedure cannot call another stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Try **Database Expert -> (left tree)Current Connections -> Add Command**

In **Add Command To Report** screen input something like:

```
EXEC dbo.StoredProcedure (param1, param2 ...)
```

In the same screen you can specify parameters for this query.

As a result, new data source, based at the query command, will be created. You can use it as an ordinary data source and place values of fields in the report area.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it like you would a table or view. Parameters (if any) will be added to your report.

Answer (score 0):

EXEC dbo.StoredProcedure param1, param2 , ...

Not input parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Pass some parameters from Crystal Report to DB packages.

Create new "Command" in Crystal Report with the same "Name" of parameter that existed in Crystal Report other "Command" and you can stored procedure normally.

For example: you were using "sum" function and received a result, and you want to stored proceduce to convert this number to "Reading way/Pronunciation" in your language, and in your DB was existed this Function before. Let's do it.